# how getview method of baseadapter class invoked

Tags: java, android

I am calling `CustomAdapter` class which extends `BaseAdapter` class and calling from other class but how `getView` method of `CustomAdapter` class will be invoked? I am not able to understand ... Please help out me..

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    public String[] sText = { "this", "that", "yellow" };
    public String bText = "hello";
    public Integer[] images = { R.drawable.s_1, R.drawable.s_2, R.drawable.s_3, };

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return sText.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return sText.length;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        View customRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lview, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) customRow.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView smalltext = (TextView) customRow.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView bigtext = (TextView) customRow.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        image.setImageResource(images[position]);
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        image.setMaxHeight(50);
        smalltext.setText(sText[position]);
        bigtext.setText(bText);
        return customRow;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe this [ListView GoogleIO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) presentation will bring some light ... It's about 45 mins, but it definitely worths watching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`how getView method of CustomAdapter class will be invoked?` 
It's a simple question that has a complex answer. You're not actually calling this method directly, but Android ListView (or any implementation of [`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html)) will call that for you. This method will be called when the list item view is ready to be displayed or about to be displayed. Maybe the correct answer would be to point you to [`ListView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java), [`AbsListView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java) and [`AdapterView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java) source codes, but I am sure you don't have enough time to review and understand that code.

So the answer I would give you is to start with the famous GoogleIO presentation, [The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70). That explains how ListView works, how it recycles its view, best practices and anti-patterns.

After you'll watch that presentation you'll see that `getView` has to end as fast as possible otherwise the `ListView` will jag and the user experience will be low. So you could implement the `ViewHolder` pattern and reuse the second parameter from `getView`.